# TestNG ERROR Cannot find class in classpath:

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have a [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) project with Selenium 2.43.1 and below is my folder structure of the project.

```
F:\SeleniumProject
F:\SeleniumProject\Workspace\UIAutomation

F:\SeleniumProject>dir

20-Mar-15  02:10 PM    <DIR>          .
20-Mar-15  02:10 PM    <DIR>          ..
21-Mar-15  10:15 AM    <DIR>          eclipse
20-Mar-15  02:10 PM    <DIR>          Firefox
20-Mar-15  12:23 PM    <DIR>          Java
20-Mar-15  12:56 PM    <DIR>          selenium-2.43.1
20-Mar-15  12:41 PM    <DIR>          Workspace



F:\SeleniumProject\Workspace\UIAutomation>dir

20-Mar-15  06:40 PM    <DIR>          .
20-Mar-15  06:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
20-Mar-15  01:17 PM             5,856 .classpath
20-Mar-15  12:36 PM               388 .project
20-Mar-15  12:36 PM    <DIR>          .settings
21-Mar-15  10:16 AM    <DIR>          bin
20-Mar-15  12:41 PM    <DIR>          src
21-Mar-15  02:38 PM    <DIR>          test-output
20-Mar-15  07:39 PM    <DIR>          testng
```

I have the .class of the test class in `src\com\ui\test\scripts`
I have the .class files of the library files in `src\com\ui\test\lib`
The `testng.xml` is in the `F:\SeleniumProject\Workspace\UIAutomation\testng` folder. When I try to execute a testng test from the command line,

```
java -cp "F:\SeleniumProject\selenium-2.43.1\libs\testng-6.8.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

it fails with the below error:

```
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: com.ui.test.scripts.VerificationOfLoginTest
```

I have tried enough to fix this, but I am unable to do it. I almost spent one day to correct this. What could have gone wrong as I can run the tests from [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) successfully?

Comment: I think this would be easier to figure out if you used a build system like Gradle.